# Why doesnt the where exist return all rows from the subquery?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

So i have 2 tables. `users` and `images`. There is a morph many relationship.

The database has 4 unique users. And each user has 1 or more entries in the images table.

I want to get all the users who have an entry in the images table.

The code currently looks like this:

```
User::whereHas('images', function (Builder $images) {
            $images->where('type', 'comment')
                ->where('images.created_at', '>=', Carbon::today());
})->get()
```

However it returns only 3 users. I want it to return all 4 users because there are 4 users in the table who have images.

The query gets translated to:

```
select * from `users` where exists (select * from `images` where `users`.`id` = `images`.`imageable_id` and `type` = 'comment' and `images`.`created_at` >= '2021-05-13 00:00:00');
```

Running the subquery like this gives me all the images for all the users:
`` select * from `images` where `type` = 'comment' and `images`.`created_at` >= '2021-05-13 00:00:00' `` so this shows that the images do exist, but adding the id column filter is removing it for some users for some reason.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `imageable_id` really the foreign key referencing users? The name seems odd...

Comment: @stickybit its a morphmany relationship. So different tables can have entries here

Comment: Ugh, that's a very ugly design... No constraints ensuring referential integrity are possible that way (unless you implement some workaround with complicated triggers). (And where is the indicator which tells us the image belongs to a user and not any other entity?) But anyway, for some user `imageable_id` doesn't match their ID.

Comment: A [example] might help to better understand this, i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.